# How can I change the color of a specific word in my external stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

Using only HTML and CSS, I would like to know how to find all instances of a word and make it red on all pages. I'm trying to do this within my external css stylesheet.

Basically, I want to be able to do something like

```
word="hello"{
    color: red;
}
```

So that every time hello appears on the screen, it's red.

Comment: Using only HTML and CSS? no you can not, but you can do this with javascript.

Comment: What does your html look like?